# I'm having trouble to create Facebook lookalike audience through API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

lookalike audience showing disabled on audience dashboard while creating through API and showing a message "Lookalikes that contain locations are being retired and can't be used in new campaigns.
", Other hand when we creating lookalike audience without location than API giving error "(#2654) Missing Locations in Lookalike Spec: The lookalike spec must contain one of location_spec or country field to create a lookalike."
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be bug on Facebook API. I also facing this issue as well. It seems like Facebook is going to remove country from lookalike spec in the future so any lookalike created with country in the spec got disabled. However, an api still require country parameter in order to create lookalike. So the best advise that I can give is to ask them to remove your account from test group by posting in the bug report like many others.

[Example of bug reports](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/4422237041164231/?join_id=f1eb93c68c3c084)

Answer (score -2):

Spec should be in a similar format
"lookalike_spec": {"type": "similarity", "country": "US"}, "origin_audience_id": "123"